# Convert non latin text to ASCII entries - without having to specify a locale

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, ascii, non-latin

I am working on a project that requires translation into 40+ languages.

I have most things all sorted but this one is really buggging me. Please take a look at this to see what I need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Purpose: Converts all non-latin based characters to their ASCII entity value
 * Usage: [String].encode()
 * Arguments: none
 * Returns: String
 */
String.prototype.encode = function() {
        return this.replace(/([^\x01-\x7E])/g, function(s) { return         "&#"+s.charCodeAt(0)+";"; });
};

/**
 * Converts all ASCII entity value characters into their unicode equivelant
 * @return (String)
 */
String.prototype.decode = function() {
        Number.prototype.toHex = function(pad) {
            var s = this.toString(16).toUpperCase();
            var v = "";
            if(typeof pad == "number") {
                    while(v.length + s.length < pad) {
                            v += "0";
                    }
            }
            return v + s;
    };
    return this.replace(/(&#([^;]*);)/g, function(s) { return unescape("%u"+        Number(RegExp.$2).toHex(4)); });
};

function translate() {
document.getElementById("txtOutput").value =         document.getElementById("txtInput").value.encode();
}
</script>

<div class="admin_block">

<h1>Translator</h1>
<p>Sometimes you need to add non latin Characters to the templates, php code and more. This tool will help you convert your text</p>
<h2>Type or paste non latin text in here</h2>
<form name="input" onmousemove="translate();">
    <textarea style="width: 900px" id="txtInput" onkeyup="translate();" onchange="translate();" onmouseup="translate();" onmousemove="translate();"></textarea>
</form>

<h2>Copy and paste this safe code below</h2>
<form onmousemove="translate();">
    <textarea style="width: 900px" id="txtOutput"></textarea><br />
    <button id="btnSelect" onclick="translate();document.getElementById('txtOutput').select(); return false;">Translate and select</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Take some Russian text, some thai etc and pop it into my awesome JS converter - it outputs the ASCII values - these values I can now use in PHP array, html templates etc and all is fine.

I am writing a new method for my PHP translation class to convert PHP language array into new languages - heres the issue. How can I get PHP to do what this JS is doing fine? I have tried htmlentities,iconv etc. I want to see translated text such as this:

```
&#1057;&#1086;&#1083;&#1086;&#1084;&#1086;&#1085;&#1086;&#1074;&#1099; &#1054;&#1089;&#1090;&#1088;&#1086;&#1074;&#1072;
```

Соломоновы Острова

Comment: There cannot be "ASCII values" for Russian, Thai, etc. ...

Comment: Why not use UTF-8? All sites should be in UTF-8.

Comment: I am using UTF8, but for my PHP files I cannot use it. look at my JS converter to see what i need

Comment: What you're talking about is **HTML entities**, not "ASCII". And why would HTML entities be necessary?

Comment: charCodeAt does not return ASCII values it returns unicode ..

Comment: OK, the issue is my editor.. it wont allow me to store UTF8 non latin chars, using this encoding has given me a workaround - there are other issues too - some of these texts are presented over an API to a mobile app that only accepts this encoding

Answer (score 0):

well this seems to give me the result I am after:

```
$s = htmlentities(mb_convert_encoding($s, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

I can now see the text result I need to copy from a browser and paste into my new array.